# Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.ISwaggerProvider' while attempting to Invoke middleware 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

I am trying to create a Web API in .NET core 3.1 however I am getting the following error -
"Unable to resolve service for type 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.ISwaggerProvider' while attempting to Invoke middleware 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware'"

I am using .NET Core 3.1 & Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen, Version=5.2.1.0

My Startup.cs is like:

```
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;           
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {            
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => builder
                           .WithOrigins(Configuration["AllowedHosts"])
                           .AllowAnyMethod()
                           .AllowAnyHeader());
        });

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);

        // Load custom configuration related to error settings.
        var errorConfig = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("errorSettings.json").Build();
        // Load settings
        services.AddOptions();
        services.Configure<SecuritySettings>(Configuration.GetSection("SecuritySettings"));
        services.Configure<ErrorSettings>(errorConfig.GetSection("ErrorSettings"));              

        // Load Database connection strings from AppSettings and load data context.
        services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDbContext")));

        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1", Description = "API" });
            // Set the comments path for the Swagger JSON and UI.
            var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
            var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
            c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
        });

        services.AddControllersWithViews()
           .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize);

        // Configure mappers
        var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(opts =>
        {
            opts.AddProfile(new AutoMapperProfile());
        });
        var mapper = mapperConfig.CreateMapper();
        services.AddSingleton<IMapper>(mapper);

        // Add Http Context Accessor
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        // Add Http client factory
        services.AddHttpClient();              

        // Add transient for Services.
        services.AddTransient<ICustomerService, CustomerService>();               
        services.AddTransient<IUserService, UserService>();

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {

        if (env.EnvironmentName == "Development")
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwagger();
        // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.),
        // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("../swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API");
            c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
        });

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");            
    }
}
}
```

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: not sure if this is something you already explored, but you might be missing `app.UseMvc();` in your `Configure()`

Comment: This error is usually caused by not adding swagger to service collection. I can't seem to reproduce the error using the code provided. I'd suggest you check if the `Configure` method is correctly called, and if at the end of it, the missing type is still in the collection.

Comment: @timur Given the OP is using ASP.Net Core 3.1, there is no need to call `UseMvc` as long as `UseEndpoint` is called: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#migrate-startupconfigure